# How Can I Change Background Color and Text Color of UITableHeaderView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I know how to provide a custom UITableview header and how to customize it. But I'm stuck while using UITableview with SectionTitles.

How I can change the color of the background color UITableview header and how I can change the text color of the UITableview header.

[Requirment illustration can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRdkm.png).

Comment: This is in documentation. Check UITableViewDelegate documentation re: header view.

Comment: i think you mean SectionHeaderView, not tableheaderview, right?

Comment: @Chris Yes, SectionHeaderView.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a customView for your header with this method:
I made an example view for you to customize it.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerView = UIView()
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        headerView.addSubview (questionLabel)
        headerView.backgroundColor = .blue
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            questionLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0),
            questionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            questionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)
            ])

        return headerView

    }
```

Comment: This solution can be used to add a customized section header.  It can't be used to customize the default section when you are using 
    `func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return [sectionTitles]
    }`

of UITableviewDataSource to show indexes.

Comment: if you have an array of titles for your headers you can do: i.e label.text = sectionTitles[section]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. This method of UITableViewDelegate can be used to customize the default section header.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        view.tintColor = .red

        if let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
            header.textLabel?.textColor = .white
        }
    }
```